# Embedding of discrete series

Tags: lie-groups, reductive-groups, induced-representations, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a simple Lie group with equal rank; namely, the rank of $G$ equals that of its maximal compact subgroup. Let $G'$ be a reductive subgroup of $G$ with equal rank. If $\tau$ is a discrete series representation of $G'$, does there exist at least one discrete series representation $\pi$ of $G$ such that $\mathrm{Hom}_{G'}(\tau,\pi|_{G'})\neq\{0\}$?

Comment: If it's possible to take $G'$ to be a proper Levi subgroup (I dunno if this can be done while still having equal rank), then no.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for your comment. But do you mean that if $G'$ a proper Levi subgroup of $G$, then for any discrete series $\tau$ of $G'$, there does not exist a discrete series representation $\pi$ such that $\mathrm{Hom}_{G'}(\tau,\pi|_{G'})\neq\{0\}$?

Comment: By Frobenius reciprocity, this would give a non-$0$ element of $\mathrm{Hom}_G(\tau^G, \pi)$.  I think that this is precluded by being in the discrete series; it certainly would be if we replaced the bare induction from $G'$ by parabolic induction.

Comment: @LSpice If $P=MAN$ is the Langlands decomposition of a cuspidal parabolic subgroup of $G$, then any tempered representation can be obtained by a parabolic induction from $P$. Hence, if $G'=MA$ is a Levi subgroup of $G$, there exists an irreducible representation $\tau$ of $G'$ such that the induced representation $\tau^G$ contains some discrete series representation of $G$. Right?

Comment: I don't even know what a cuspidal parabolic subgroiup is, so I think I'll slink back to the setting of $p$-adic groups where I know what I'm talking about.  :-)